# Is there any way to have two applications visible at the same time, with one application not in use overlapping the other

Tags: macos, window-manager

For example:

[image]

Notice how Sublime Text 2 (the application on the right) is visible and I can see chrome in the background. This is expected behaviour as I have Sublime Text 2 open and in use.

But then when I swap back to Chrome, the app disappears in the background, because chrome is now in use (which I guess is expected behaviour).

[image: second pic]

Is there any way so that when I swap back to Chrome, I can see other applications on top of it? In other words, can I use Chrome and look at other applications on top of it?

Obviously I could do something side by side, but my real problem involves an application that I maximise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the option to "float" apps. 
Before I give my answer, I should say that you need to do a bit of Google on "How to keep apps on top on mac" 
With this, I found that this was already mentioned before in [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/182016/keep-a-window-always-on-top-in-mac-os-x)
If you are too lazy or have slow internet, the answer mentioned was [Afloat](https://github.com/millenomi/afloat/), since Afloat is open  source, install guide [here](http://www.chrisvanpatten.com/master-windows-afloat-mac).

Comment: I definitely was googling for the wrong thing, thank you :)

Comment: yaay! I now can comment! Thank you very much TerryA!

Comment: Enjoy the privilege :P